# how to fix errors in generated code

Tags: java, android

Hi! Recently I started to learn Android development, and while making a project from a book,I got into a problem in running the project code. I had to do a photo gallery. All went well, but when I try to run it, I get an error in R.java class automatically generated by Eclipse. After class R has been generated I found that at the end of the class a brace is missing. I tried to edit the code but Eclipse won't let me. I created another project and I got the source code from the book and the same error appeared in class R (the last brace was not generated).
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to simply delete `R.java` in your filesystem and run the application.

Comment: Errors in `R` is a very common issue. You should never edit it though. Search around for possible solutions. The first thing I'd try is to clean the project.

Comment: errors like this are usually related to the layout configurations, check your xml files.

Comment: clean and build your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1.- Import the project into eclipse (File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace)

2.- In Eclipse, Manually create gen folder and add it as source folder (right click on the project: Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add folder)

3.- Clean the project, you suppose to get R.java well generated

Answer (score 1):

Try these.....

**-** Delete the `R.java` file, then **clean** the project.

**-** See, is there any error in your `.xml` file, which are used to define your `layouts`.

**-** Don't do any manual changes to the `R.java file`, its an auto-generated file which contains the `constants`, grouped according to their **xml resource type**.

Comment: I tryed deleting the R.Java file and when I ran the project it regeneratd it with the same error , I've rewritten the xml code but nwo it says that it can not find the photo gallery

Comment: @did you clean the project after deleting it